# List channel messages $top parameter causes unexpected results

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

Trying to limit the number of results returned by the [List channel messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) Graph API. However, when setting `$top` to e.g. 10, then only 3 messages are returned. When setting it to 30, then 19 messages are returned. Does `$top` count deleted messages that aren't returned or something like that? Is this a bug?

How do I reliably get the last 10 messages? Do I really have to ask for e.g. 30 and then filter out the rest?

Comment: As per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging) different Graph APIs will behave differently towards $top when specified. But for this endpoint, I am seeing just the expected behavior. What client are you using to make the call?

Comment: Yes, I am also seeing the same expected behavior as @Danstan said. have you tried using [Graph Explorer](https://aka.ms/ge)? Make sure you are trying it in v1.0 version.

Comment: I am using a NodeJS http client, but using Curl for example produces the same result:
`curl "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/***/channels/***@thread.tacv2/messages?\$top=5" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer ***"`
This returns a result with "@odata.count":2. But then using $top=20 I get a result list with "@odata.count":13,"...

Comment: Update: When using the /beta endpoint, $top works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

When fetching all users in organization in the C# SDK, I ran into something similar. Running .Distinct() on the result set reduced the number of records to the expected amount.

BaseUrl for client appears to be  `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0`